# Pytest teardown log hides test summary

Tags: python, pytest

E.g. when I have a test folder consisting of this `conftest.py`

```
def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    for _ in range(100):
        print('some teardown log msg')
```

and this `test_x.py`

```
def test_x():
    pass
```

the output of `pytest -v` will be

```
================================ test session starts ================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.1.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- 
(...)
collected 1 item                                                                    

../../../../../tmp/test_project/test_x.py::test_x PASSED                      [100%]

================================= 1 passed in 0.02s =================================
some teardown log msg
some teardown log msg
some teardown log msg
...
...
... (100 Lines)
```

Due to the log messages I cannot see the summary without scrolling up.

Using `-rsxpf` does not improve that, as the "Report" produced by `-r` will also appear *before* the teardown log.

Is there a way to call `pytest` such that the relevant summary can be seen without scrolling up, whilst keeping the teardown log? E.g. by changing the position of the summary, repeating it at the end, or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

you can reverse the output

on linux :

```
pytest -v | tac
```

on Mac

```
pytest -v | tail -r
```

[image]

Comment: while this technically works in my demo case, it unfortunately does not in real examples with more than a hand full of tests. I cannot fomat this accordingly in this comment, but basically the point is just that this will show the *first N lines* while the summary is not in this range.